# How to convert a number string from lets say 12,345,645 to 12.3M

Tags: string, formatting

is there an easy way to do this?

the data i get will be a string like "123,456,789"

i want to rewrite as 123.4M or 123.5M rounded, i guess ill add on the "M"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide it by 1,000,000 and round it to whatever precision you want, then append "M".  If you tell us what programming language maybe I can offer an example.

Comment: thanks for the tip! i was thinking too much of it lols. but i just formatted the the string then divide by 1mil then append M. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to strip the commas, and then divide the number by 1,000,000. If you're always going to do it in millions... If you're going to want "k" and so on, then you'll need to check how long the string is.

```
string.strip(",")
if string.length > 3 && string.length < 7
     double = double(string)/1000;
     formattedString = string(double) + "K"     
else if string.length > 6 && string.length < 10
     double = double(string)/1000000;
     formattedString = string(double) + "M"
```

Granted, that's pseudo-code so...

Comment: Checking the length of a string is a poor way to check the magnitude of the number it represents.  Better would be to convert the string to a number and check if it's >= 1000000, then >= 1000.

Comment: also data i get will definitely be at least in the millions, minimum 7 digit numbers..